# HTML CSS разные позиции элементов

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, есть div, и button. Оба имеют display: inline-block; и одинаковый height, но дело в том что отображаются они не корректно, один чуть выше другого, см скрин.

Не подскажите как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь - vertical-align:top

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Для div и button нужно добавить vertical-align: top или middle или bottom, но не baseline)
2. Стоит задать для div и button паддинги, или обнулить их - видно что, тексты стоят криво.